# Using dropdownlist to auto populate page during pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and my title might be a bit confusing so let me explain, also I might be doing this the wrong way so if you have any suggestions that would be great.

When a user logs into my site they are given a dropdownlist of their client and site. They can have multiple clients or sites. Once they log in they are sent to a general dashboard displaying information about the site.

I made a user control for the the sitedrop down called Sitepicker which populates the 2 dropdown lists using a stored procedure. Many users only have 1 client and site, so I wanted it to auto select the first client and site that is populated in the dropdownlist and use that for the general dashboard.

This how I populate the sites dropdownlist.

```
    void PopulateSiteList()
    {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            da.AddParameter("portaluserid", Page.User.Identity.Name, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLString, 256);
            da.AddParameter("ClientID", Session["ClientID"], DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
            DataSet SiteList = da.runSPDataSet("Portal_SitePickerSiteList");

            DropDownListSite.DataSource = SiteList;
            DropDownListSite.DataValueField = "SiteID";
            DropDownListSite.DataTextField = "SiteName";
            DropDownListSite.DataBind();
    }
```

Here is the pageload of the sitepicker.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {       
            if (Session["ClientName"] != null)
                ClientButton.Text = Session["ClientName"].ToString();
            if (Session["SiteName"] != null)
                SiteButton.Text = Session["SiteName"].ToString();

            LoadClientDDL();

            if (DropDownListClient.Items.Count.Equals(1))
            {
                ClientButton.Enabled = false;
                DropDownListClient.Visible = false;
                int ClientID = int.Parse(DropDownListClient.SelectedItem.Value);
                ClientButton.Text = DropDownListClient.SelectedItem.Text;
                ClientButton.Visible = true;
                Session["ClientID"] = ClientID;
                Session["ClientName"] = DropDownListClient.SelectedItem.Text;

                {
                    PopulateSiteList();

                }

                if (DropDownListSite.Items.Count > 0)

                {
                    DropDownListSite.SelectedIndex = 1;
                    DropDownListSite.Visible = false;
                    SiteButton.Visible = true;
                    int SiteID = int.Parse(DropDownListSite.SelectedItem.Value);
                    SiteButton.Text = DropDownListSite.SelectedItem.Text;

                    Session["SiteID"] = SiteID;
                    Session["SiteName"] = DropDownListSite.SelectedItem.Text;

                }
            }
```

So that all works very well. My problem is once my general dashboard page loads, none of the lables update unless I hit refresh.

Here is the page_load for the general dashboard

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["SiteID"] != null)
        {
            SiteID = int.Parse(Session["SiteID"].ToString());
             PopulateAccountData();
             PopulateAccountInformation2();
             PopulateSiteNodes();

        }
        else
             LabelSiteName.Text = "No Site Selected";
    }

void PopulateAccountData()
    {

        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        da.AddParameter("SiteID", SiteID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
        SiteHeader = da.runSPDataSet("Portal_GetDashboardInfo");

        LabelGeneralManagerFirstName.Text = SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
        LabelGeneralManagerLastName.Text = SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();
        LabelSite.Text = SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SiteName"].ToString();
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Once the user logs in they are directed to the dashboard page and it will always show No Site Selected unless they refresh.

Any ideas on how to properly do this?

HTML Code for site Picker

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:Button ID="ClientButton" runat="server" OnClick="ClientButton_Click" Text="Select Client" /></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListClient" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListClient_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="False" Height="36px">
    </asp:DropDownList></td>

<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>    
<td><asp:Button ID="SiteButton" runat="server" OnClick="SiteButton_Click" Text="Select Site" /></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top"><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSite" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListSite_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="False" Height="36px">
    </asp:DropDownList></td>


</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add your HTML for this control to your question. Also, I don't see anywhere where you're setting a value for Session["SiteID"]. Am I missing it?

Comment: Thanks John, Sorry about that, could of sworen I read tags in title, Thank you for correcting my mistake.

Comment: Melanie- I added the html code for the picker, I hope that is what you were wondering about. I use SiteID in other things, like the to populate the account list, I have a stored procedure that uses the siteID to give me back account numbers. I didn't post it because it was getting lengthy in code.

Comment: I notice you're setting `DropDownListSite.SelectedIndex` to 1.  That would be appropriate if you had a dummy entry at index 0, but I don't see where you add one, unless it's coming back from the data source.

Comment: This may be a silly question to ask, but:  are the dashboard and the site picker in the same web project?  If they're not, they're not going to share session and `Session["SiteID"]` will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're thinking of is a `postback`

Go to your xhtml and make sure `AutoPostback="True"` on your dropdownlist.

This will "`postback`" and cause your page to refresh and apply changes.  This allows is how client and server communication occurs in asp.net.

This may be a good resource for more info for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720416(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It is set to true. Which works for when they select the client. Sorry I was a bit confusing with my question and I will update it, but when they first load into the general dashboard the dropdownlist will auto select the first client and site (Many users only have 1 of each). So there is my problem. If they do select a new site from the dropdownlist it will postback with the correct values. It's more of the first initial load that is causing me problems.